# Verify that two linear representations are equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I've a problem in verifying that two linear representations are equivalent.

First of all, I have two permutation representations of the group $G=\langle\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma\rangle$ on the set $X=\{1,...,7\}$.

The first permutation representation is defined as follows:

$\alpha\longmapsto \bar{\alpha}=(73)(62)$, 
$\;\beta\longmapsto \bar{\beta}=(35)(24)$,
$\;\gamma\longmapsto \bar{\gamma}=(56)(21)$

The second permutation representation is:

$\alpha\longmapsto \bar{\alpha}=(46)(57)$, 
$\;\beta\longmapsto \bar{\beta}=(24)(53)$,
$\;\gamma\longmapsto \bar{\gamma}=(12)(65)$

Now I have to verify that the two associated linear representations $U$ and $U'$ are equivalent, i.e that exists a matrix $S$ such that$\;U(g)S=SU'(g)\;for\; all\;g\in\:G$.

In order to find the matrix representations associated, I identified every permutation with the corresponding permutation matrix and I obtained symmetric matrices with the same set of eigenvalues.

I have tried to find S looking at the matrices associated to the $\alpha$'s permutations using the function 'eig' of Matlab (if $V$ is the matrix of the eigenvectors, obtained with 'eig' for the first $\alpha$, and P is the one for the second $\alpha$, S should be $V{P}^-$).

However since the permutations associated to the $\gamma$'s  are the same, $S$ has to commute with the corresponding matrix permutation of$\gamma$ but, trying with Matlab, I don't obtain this.

Could someone please tell me where I am mistaking? Thanks!

Comment: If $G$ is a group, which element is the identity?

Comment: Of G is only said that it is generated by three elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&1&0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right)$$
seems to work. (Your approach looks OK, and I am afraid I do not know where you are going wrong.)

Using a bit more theory, the group is ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$, and the permutation representations are doubly transitive, so the corresponding matrix representations must decompose as a sum of $1$- and $6$-dimensional irreducibles. But ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ only has one $6$-dimensional irreducible (their dimensions are $1,3,3,6,7,8$), so the two representations have to be equivalent.

Comment: could you also please tell me how did you find this S?